# Can't find where to download VEST package for Mathematica

Tags: packages, commercial-package

In the Internet I have found the article about the VEST package for abstract vector calculus simplification in Mathematica. http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2561 However, I can not find any reference for downloading this package. Does anybody know where I can download this package?

Comment: Why don't you send an email to the authors and ask them?  Most likely you won't get an answer here.  If you contact them, you will.

Comment: I have already sent, but to be on the safe side I decided to ask here too. Maybe someone have already faced this problem and know the answer. After all, if I find the answer I will share it here and I hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Sounds good, do post the answer if you find out.

Comment: It can be downloaded [here](http://www.cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/) if your institution is a subscriber to Elsevier's Computer Physics Communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found where to download this package. http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AEQN_v1_0.html
But it is free only if your institution is a subscriber to Elsevier's Computer Physics as  Sjoerd C. de Vries mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds like yet another reason to avoid Elsevier as much as possible.  It is bad enough that [aggressive](http://svpow.com/2013/12/06/elsevier-is-taking-down-papers-from-academia-edu/) for-profit publishers hold control of so many articles and actively try prevent access to them by those who don't pay.  It is completely unacceptable that the same would happen to software libraries as well.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about this, I was under the impression the CPC library was available to everybody. I tried to upload the code to arXiv but it didn't work, so the Mathematica package and a tutorial notebook can now be found on [ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/256477130_VEST_abstract_vector_calculus_simplification_in_Mathematica) or [github](https://github.com/jonosquire/VEST). Hopefully I can set up a more convenient spot for people to download the package soon.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41907/how-to-take-derivative-of-parameterized-coordinate)?  Is your package useful for these types of calculations?

Comment: Possibly using some extra function definitions on top of the the basic functionality. However, the requirement of general n (vector size) might be a little problematic, since VEST is essentially set to be either 3 or 6 dimensional.