# Derivative of a function in undefined dimension

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, tensors

I have a scalar function defined on a $ n $-dimensional manifold:
$ f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) $, where $ n $ is undefined, and $x_i$ are the coordinates.
How to define something like "$∂_af∂^af$"?

(I'm solving the Einstein equation for a black brane in the large-N limit, where N is the dimension of the brane, so I should keep N in my expression instead of setting N as something like 5)

I've tried:

```
In[10]:=f/:D[f[i_],x[j_]]=f[i+x[j]]
In[11]:=D[f[0],x[5]]
Out[11]:=f[x[5]]
```

That's OK but then

```
In[13]:=D[-f[0],x[5]]
Out[13]:=0
```

It doesn't work now:(

**Edit:**

My current solution is just

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {f}]
```

It almost perfectly solved my problem despite the complicated output. I'm not trying to simplify the output.

Comment: What is `a`, then?

Comment: potentially related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41907/7936 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16375/7936

Comment: Yes, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41907/7936 seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If only constants are the problem, this could help:

```
 x /: D[c_. f[i_], x[j_]] = c f[i + x[j]]
```